# html proof and footer on the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm pretty new with bootstrap and css. Firstly, I would like to know if the code I wrote is correct. Working with more containers is fine? I use fluid containers for header and footer (width 100% vw), and a standard container for the contents.

Secondly, I m not sure what is the best way to code my footer. I need it on the bottom of the page, but not fixed with absolute position (I dont want it fixed in the browser window).
I tried different solutions without succeding. Shall I nest all my containers in another one?

Thank you so much, and sorry if I didn't explain perfectly or I missed anything.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div clas="col-xs-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-brand no_margins">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">
                                About
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Works
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                News
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Contacts
                            </a>
                        </li>


                    </ul>


                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- close container navbar-->

<!-- header -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <header class="col-xs-12 static_header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 hidden-xs logo_header">
                    <img src="images/logo_header.png" />

                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 title_header">
                    <h1>
                        My Title
                    </h1>


                </div>
            </div>


        </header>

    </div>

</div>

<!-- end header -->


<!-- content -->
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="content_box">
                <h2>
                    About
                </h2>

                <p>
                   my text
                </p>
                ​


            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- end content -->

<footer class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 contact_footer">
                        <a href="#">info@site.com</a><br>
                        <a href="#">+1 234567890</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer_social_bar" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <img src="images/fb.png"/>
                        <img src="images/linkedin.png"/>
                        <img src="images/twitter.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 copyright">
                        © 2017, company

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: that looks like a fine `footer`. What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: Is not always on the bottom. Sometimes is in the middle of the page, when the browser' window is not fullscreen.

here the css I wrote:



footer {
  background-color: #383838;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
position: absolute;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about viewers using a screen that is far bigger than the content you have in your website, you can use the following css to make sure that the site is at least as big as their browser.

```css
html{
 height:100%;
}
body{
 min-height:100%;
 background-color:#0C0;
}
```

```html
<p>I only have a small amount of content. But the body background-color is as big as the screen</p>
```

Comment: I copied your styles in my css, and I removed the position: absolute from the footer' style (with that, the footer had a fixed width).
actually the footer works strangely. sometimes is on the bottom and seems working fine, sometimes not (in other words, below the footer sometimes there is a green row - the color of the body, of course) I can't see any logic. In the css there is not anything else that could interfare...

where am I wrong?

Comment: @mauri, you'll need to either leave the `position:absolute;` or add a similar `min-height` to your content section like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8yzp9ptm/). I added a `#content` div around the header and content, then set the `min-height:calc(100vh - 40px); /* 100% of the window - height of the footer  */`

Comment: Another doubt. I googled but I have not find any solution.
With a responsive layout, I don't know the height of the footer. I need Javascript, right?

Comment: if your footer is likely to change size, then yeah, you'll need that if you want perfectly positioned footer from the bottom of the page.. however, we are only looking at `min-height`, so as long as you accommodate for the smallest size your footer is likely to be your `min-height` should still mean the footer is "just" visible when the page is smaller than the browser height

Comment: I increased the height of the footer (min-heigth: 120px) to avoid a free space below (maybe 40px was not enough, I've no idea), and now seems working perfectly also without JS.
Also with a long disclaimer, works great.
thank you!!!

Comment: Youre welcome. Feel free to mark this as the answer if your problem has been solved. I will add the jsfiddle and calc code as soon as im off my phone